# Oracle IF inside CASE

Tags: oracle

How can I use an `if elsif` inside a `case` when using Oracle 11G?

I want to end with the `type_pre` value with 3 or 4 based on another column: `gr.gt_id`.

I try to run and the error message is missing keyword.

Is there a better way to do this task ?

```
CASE
   WHEN certv.id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
   WHEN cert.id IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF gr.gt_id = 0 THEN type_pre = 3
      ELSIF gr.gt_id = 1 THEN type_pre = 4
      END IF
   WHEN not.id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
END as type_pre,
```

Comment: Are you doing this in plain SQL, or in a PL/SQL procedure/function/etc.?

Comment: It is a view but into a plain sql will work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CASE
   WHEN certv.id IS NOT NULL                  THEN NULL
   WHEN cert.id  IS NOT NULL and gr.gt_id = 0 THEN 3
   WHEN cert.id  IS NOT NULL and gr.gt_id = 1 THEN 4
   WHEN not.id   IS NOT NULL                  THEN NULL
END as type_pre,
```

Comment: thank´s @mahguy it is working so succintly the diferences in the sql syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I see no one explained you mistakes, so let me tell me where you wen't wrong :

First, no need for nested IF's/Case's , it can be done with a single case each time like @mathguy answer.

`IF` is used in PL/SQL and cannot be used directly in oracle, so if you wanted to do it in your method, with nested conditions, then this should have been your query:

```
CASE
      WHEN certv.id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN cert.id IS NOT NULL THEN
        CASE WHEN gr.gt_id = 0 THEN = 3 
             WHEN gr.gt_id = 1 THEN = 4 END
      WHEN not.id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
    END as type_pre,
```

Your second problem beside the use of `IF` was the use of a statement in the `THEN` part. This is a `CASE EXPRESSION` , it can be used to put a value, not a statement, which is why i removed the type_pre part.